# Fetch ntpdate offset value in a variable in python

Tags: linux, python, time, synchronization, ntp

I wish to check if the offset timing is greater than 0.5 seconds and do some action.
I am running the command `ntpdate -q <Server ip address>`

Can someone tell me how should I capture the offset value in a variable so that I can perform further action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output('ntpdate -q 3.us.pool.ntp.org | head -1 | cut -d " " -f 6 | sed "s/.$//"', shell=True)
```

You can change the "3.us.pool.ntp.org" servername to the NTP server of your choice.

With this method, the output variable will contain *only* the offset stated in the first line of the ntpdate command output and you can do what you wish with that figure after.

```
if output > X:
    do something...
```

**Explanation**

You already know what ntpdate does (clearly) so you'll know that the output that it comes back with has a lot of useless information for what you are trying to do.

- Subprocess allows you to run bash commands from within your python script
- check_output does exactly what it says on the tin and, in this case, stores it in the output variable.
- head -1 simply takes the top line of the ntpdate output if using a pool like I did in my example (the various results *shouldn't* vary a great deal so the top should be fine).
- cut treats the lines as fields delimited by a space character. It sorts through and picks out the 6th field which is the offset value.
- sed removes the last character from that value, which is a comma and will ruin any attempt you make to actually use the value.
- shell=True invokes a shell to carry out the deed.

~~~~~~~~~**EDIT**~~~~~~~~~~~

I also don't have the rep to comment, ha. Could you please let me know which version of python the server is running @Iram Khan?

```
python -V
```

I suspect it's a version < 2.7 as that was when the check_output functionality was added. In that case you may have to alter the above to:

```
import subprocess

cmd = "ntpdate -q 3.us.pool.ntp.org | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 6 | sed 's/.$//'"

ps = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

output = ps.communicate()[0]
```

This should do it if check_output won't work.

Comment: Now I can comment it seems. Thanks I_GNU_it_all_along. Your edited answer helped me. Thanks again. Happppy coding....

Comment: No bother man. Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Use backtics `` for command evaluation and assign output to variable

```
OFFSET=`ntpdate -q <Server ip address>  |sed 's/.*\(offset\) \([0-9]\.[0-9]\+\).*/\2/'`
if [[ $OFFSET -gt 0.5 ]]; then
   <do something...>
fi
```

Comment: I need to get Offset value in python script not shell script